# OpenCV, JNI and Windows 7 64-bit causes black video screen

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface

I have a program that uses OpenCV (2.3.1) to analyze webcam-images, and I want to start this program in Java (7) using JNI (Java Native Interface).

The problem:
Since I have moved to a new computer (with Windows 7 64 bit, while my old computer had Windows XP) it doesn't work anymore. No errors, exceptions or anything, but the camera-feed is simply black. When I create an executable and start that directly, it works like a charm, but when I create a DLL and start it from Java, I see the black screen again. On my old computer it worked with both ways.

I've tried using and compiling 32-bit version of everything (OpenCV 32-bit files, compiling to 32 bit, using 32-bit Java), and I've tried 64-bit version of everything (including 64-bit Java and Eclipse), but I keep looking at a black screen.

Is there anyone out there who knows what the problem is, how to solve it, or how to perform additional tests to find the problem?

Huge thanks in advance,

Mark tM

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCV` self's bug. You should use the OpenCV trunk code, and compile it by yourself.

The SVN check-out url : `https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/`